# Change class names dynamically added to html elements by wordpress

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to wordpress theming and I am working on a theme that uses the newest Twitter Bootstrap.

Here is my question:
WordPress adds class names to html elements based on whats going on ie:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-36"><a href="#">Category</a></li>
</ul>
```

It added the class submenu to the ul, the id menu-item-36 and classes menu-item, menuitem-type-custom, etc to the first list item.

Twitter bootstrap already has styles defined for most of this. How do I change the names of the classes generated by wordpress?

I feel like it would be more of a pain and not good for updates to change these styles names in the bootstrap css file

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful removing WordPress classes. Some plugins may depend on those classes.

You should be able to pretty easily add your own classes though, [as explained in the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items). You'd use the `nav_menu_css_class` filter to alter or add those classes. See the Codex for an example of doing so. I don't know what classes twitter bootstrap wants or needs so I can't really write code for it, and I imagine it would be quite a bit of code anyway to include all the different classes conditionally.